# Falta el punto 4 del artículo "¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?" del Centro de Ayuda

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva, estado-por-diseño, traducciones

> ## Resumen:
>
> Traducir y agregar el punto 4 de la [versión en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) de [**¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Revisando esta pregunta [Alternativas a Eclipse para desarrollar en J2EE](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/871/alternativas-a-eclipse-para-desarrollar-en-j2ee), inmediatamente pensé en cerrarla puesto que es off-topic (no es relevante en el sitio), sin embargo al tratar de cerrarla me di cuenta que ya habían votado por cerrarla con el motivo

> **se basa principalmente en opiniones**

Sin embargo este no es el motivo correcto. El motivo correcto es:

> **no relacionado porque...** >  Esta pregunta no parece versar sobre programación, dentro del alcance definido en el centro de ayuda.

Sin embargo me puse a pensar porque los demás habían escogido esa opción así que entré a la ayuda: [**¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para encontrar el motivo específico de porque es mejor cerrarla como offtopic y me di con la sorpresa que el motivo por el cual esta pregunta debe ser cerrada, no existe en el sitio en español.

El artículo del centro de ayuda en español: [**¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) difiere del mismo artículo en la versión en inglés: [**What topics can I ask about here?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) en los puntos 4, 5 y 6 y el texto final:

> 4. Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.
> 5. Questions about *general computing hardware and software* are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.
> 6. Questions on *professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration* are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools.
>
> **If your question is not specifically on-topic for Stack Overflow**, it may be on topic for [another Stack Exchange site](http://stackexchange.com/sites). If your question would be of interest to ...
>
> - Computer enthusiasts and power users, ask on [Super User](http://superuser.com).
> - Professional system and network administrators, ask on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com).
> - Users of TeX, LaTeX, ConTeXt, and related typesetting systems, ask on [TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com).
> - Database administrators and professionals, ask on [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com).
> - SharePoint enthusiasts, ask on [SharePoint Stack Exchange](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com).
>
> If no site currently exists that will accept your question, you may [commit to](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) or [propose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site) a new site at [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), the place where new Stack Exchange communities are democratically created.

Entiendo que el punto 5, el 6 y el texto final no son apropiados para nuestro sitio porque los otros sitios no tiene equivalente en español pero el punto 4 definitivamente debe estar incluido en la versión en español

Propongo el siguiente texto:

> 4. Preguntas pidiéndonos *recomendar o encontrar un libro, herramienta, biblioteca de software, tutorial u otro recurso en otro sitio* no son relevantes  para Stack Overflow porque tienden a atraer respuestas basadas en opiniones y contenido no deseado. En lugar de eso, [describe el problema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399) y qué has hecho hasta el momento para resolverlo.

Y su fuente en markdown:

```
4. Preguntas pidiéndonos *recomendar o encontrar un libro, herramienta, biblioteca de software, tutorial u otro recurso en otro sitio* no son relevantes  para Stack Overflow porque tienden a atraer respuestas basadas en opiniones y contenido no deseado. En lugar de eso, [describe el problema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399) y qué has hecho hasta el momento para resolverlo.
```

Además tambien el cuadro que sale con los motivos de cierra son diferentes.

#### Español

[image: Cierre en español]

#### Inglés

[image: Cierre en inglés]

Habría que tambien incluir las opciones 4 y 5 del cuadro en inglés en nuestra versión

Comment: Y ahora que lo noto el markdown del primer parrafo en el link y  `**código**` tampoco esta funcionando correctamente

Comment: Corregí el markdown. :)

Answer (score 1):

No quise poner ese obstáculo aquí porque siento que una pregunta así, aunque no aceptable en el sitio de inglés, puede convertirse en wiki de comunidad y ser muy útil a largo plazo en nuestra comunidad.

La omisión fue hecha a propósito.