# ¿Es correcto preguntar por un libro?

Tags: soporte

me pregunto si puedo pedir recomendación acerca de algún libro que toque un tema muy específico, por ejemplo: Pedir recomendación de un libro que trate sobre como aprender el paradigma de la programación orientada a objetos usando python.

Comment: Relacionado: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1811/65

Comment: Relacionado: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/248/65

Answer (score 2):

## Respuesta corta

Lo dudo mucho porque en otros sitios similares de la red no se permiten preguntas sobre recomendaciones (respuestas basadas en opiniones). Considera proponerlo en [Definición de la temática apropiada para el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/161/65) pero planteado de otra forma.

## Explicación

Stack Overflow en español aún se encuentra, aunque por muy poco tiempo, en fase de beta pública y además por ser uno de los pocos sitios internacionales tiene algunas cosas distintas a o otros sitios en la red de Stack Exchange, por lo que si se plantea de forma correcta, podría tener posibilidades.

Una de las cosas distintas es que tenemos un hilo para proponer temas a ser abordados. Se trata de [Definición de la temática apropiada para el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/161/65). En este hilo aún nadie propone que se pueda preguntar por libros u otros recursos de aprendizaje.

Cabe mencionar que el modelo de este sitio está enfocado a preguntas sobre problemas prácticos que enfrenta la comunidad de programadores y que puedan tener respuesta práctica, es decir, que es posible determinar que una respuesta es buena con base en que su utilidad para resolver el problema en cuestión, no que se base en cuestiones de preferencias personales ni que se conviertan en "listas de compras".

En lo personal, tengo la mente abierta, pero aún no se me ocurre<sup>1</sup> cómo se podría preguntar por un libro de forma

- que sea bien percibida por la comunidad de Stack Overflow en español (SOes)
- coherente con los temas permitidos en SOes
- tal que las respuestas no estén basadas en opiniones

> <sup>1</sup> Pues ya se nos ocurrió. Véase [Propuesta: Lista de libros de C++ en la etiqueta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1811/65)

## Artículos de ayuda relacionados

- [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
- [¿Qué tipo de preguntas debo evitar preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

## Sitios sobre "medios de soporte de contenido" o contenido mismo

- https://ebooks.stackexchange.com
- https://movies.stackexchange.com

## Excepción (sitio que si permite recomendaciones)

- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: Dentro de las condiciones, creo que con la que menos encaja es con "que tenga una respuesta única".

Comment: @Mariano: En el caso del ejemplo dado por el OP, estoy de acuerdo que no hay una respuesta única. Justo se me ocurrió que se podría preguntar cuál es el libro en el que se publicó por primera vez el paradigma orientado a objetos, pero seguramente no pasaría la prueba de buscar/investigar sobre el tema, lo cual no sería algo grave porque es usual que "la comunidad" publique respuestas a este tipo de preguntas.

Comment: quizás algo así podría entrar como [TAG:historia], que sí fue aceptado por la comunidad. Pero no creo que sea exactamente lo mismo que está preguntando... Creo que es una lástima que ese tipo de preguntas no entren dentro del modelo de preguntas y respuestas de SE, y sí quizás entrarían como Documentation, pero lo tomo como parte de lo que se debe dejar de lado para que el sitio funcione mejor.

Comment: @Mariano: Están [ebooks.se], [movies.se] y posiblemente otros, así que "algún día" podríamos tener un sitio sobre libros en español :)

Comment: Buen punto. Ninguno de esos es sobre recomendaciones, y siguen teniendo respuestas únicas, pero [softwarerecs.se] es una buena excepción

Comment: Tu lo dudas. Pero yo tengo la certeza total de que sí se permite en inglés, de forma muy limitada : [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) y [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). En este sitio, sencillamente no lo sabemos. Por cierto, ¿a quién corresponde decidir tal cosa?

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos: Nótese que ambas referencias se encuentran con estado "locked" y que una fue publican en el 2008 y la otra en el 2009. Estas publicaciones se conservan por su valor histórico y no deben ser utilizadas como referencia de lo que se permite o no **actualmente**, en términos de nuevas publicaciones. En cuanto a quien le corresponde decir tal cosa y otras similares, te sugiero publicar una pregunta al respecto.

Comment: Notese que hoy, veinte de abril de dos mil diecisiete, "Las respuestas de esta pregunta son un esfuerzo colaborativo: si ves algo que puede ser mejorado, ¡simplemente edita la respuesta para mejorarla! No se aceptan más respuestas" Es decir, hoy se acepta el añadir nuevos libros que hayan salido sobre C++ y C. No se mantiene solo por valor histórico, se mantiene como un recurso valioso que hay que actualizar, por ejemplo con libros sobre c++14 que, evidentemente, no fueron incluidos en las respuestas en 2008 o 2009.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos, estamos en abril, no en febrero :)

Comment: Pues sí, tienes razon en eso :)

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos: ¡Me has hecho el día!

Answer (score 1):

En este repo hay libros de todo, en español:

https://github.com/vhf/free-programming-books/blob/master/free-programming-books-es.md

Comment: Esta publicación resultó de una conversión en el chat, véase http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36837646#36837646

Answer (score 0):

Si haces una pregunta como esa pueden pasar varias cosas:

- Que se cierre (closed) porque la respuesta estará basada en opiniones. Y la pregunta acabe quedando desechada e incluso borrada.
- Que se cierre (locked) y acabe convertida en un esfuerdo cooperativo (wiki).

¿Qué pasará? Hay una forma de averiguarlo...

Probablemente el número de preguntas sobre libros que se toleren en el sitio sea reducido. Con lo que si quieres tener alguna posibilidad de tener éxito es mejor que preguntes sobre Python en general. Y puedes añadir que también te interesa la POO en Python, lo cual sería un apartado de la respuesta, no toda.