# Donde puedo hacer preguntas relacionadas con recomendaciones, libros,

Tags: discusión, soporte, preguntas

Simple, quisiera saber donde puedo preguntar recomendaciones, libros donde buscar y demás cosas, ya  que cuando lo intento me cierran las preguntas

Comment: En el sitio, una de las causales de cierre de preguntas es justamente la solicitud de recomendaciones, pero con tu reputación entiendo que podrías probar en el [chat]

Comment: que yo sepa no hay un sitio en la red con ese objetivo... el cual no estaria mal.

Comment: Stack Overflow (en español o en ingles) no son lugares adecuados. Si no prefieres el chat y no hay sitios en la red, entonces tendrás que buscar algún foro en internet.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Es correcto preguntar por un libro?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1786/es-correcto-preguntar-por-un-libro)

Comment: @Rubén Si y no, aunque mas que si que en que no XD