# Propuesta: Lista de libros de C++ en la etiqueta

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

Una lista de libros en español sobre C++ resultaría útil para muchos usuarios del sitio.

Pero recomendar un libro se sale de la temática del sitio.

Por lo que propongo poner esta lista en la [etiqueta de C++](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2B%2B/info). Y que la forma de decidir qué libros poner en esa lista sea votándolos como respuestas en esta pregunta.

Es decir, quien quiera proponer un libro pondría una respuesta con el título del libro y su autor. Si está disponible de forma libre un enlace.

A la etiqueta se le añadirían los libros que superen un criterio de votos todavía por decidir.

- El libro debe ser en español.
- Debes haberlo leído tu mismo. Si conoces a alguien que habla maravillas de un libro que no has leido esta podría ser una buena ocasión para invitarle a que se una.
- Incluye el título oficial y su autor o autores.
- Si el libro está diponible de forma libre, incluye un enlace.
- Pon un pequeño resumen del libro y de por qué lo recomiendas.

Comment: me parece muy buena idea y quizas este post se pueda tambien convertir en algo similar a este -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list pues parece que esta permitido pues esta bloquedo pero dice algo asi: **Las respuestas de esta pregunta son un esfuerzo de colaboración: si ves algo que se puede mejorar, apenas corrige la respuesta a mejorarlo! No hay respuestas adicionales se pueden agregar aquí**. Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel Esa era mi idea original. Pero hablándolo con Rubén en el chat llegamos a la conclusión de que eso no encaja en la temática del sitio y que el mejor sitio para hacerlo es la etiqueta de C++. Nuestra conversación empezó más o menos [aquí](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36836430#36836430). Lo que has puesto en negrita es uno de los argumentos que yo mismo le expuse a Rubén. Pero me convenció de no hacerlo en el sitio principal.

Comment: Relacionado: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/248/65

Comment: discrepo, porque ya nadie hace buenos libros de C++ en español ya que en el mercado de las personas de habla hispana, casi nadie usa C++ todos estan con Java y C#, los unicos **libros buenos** que conozco son desde el 1988 hasta el 2010, ya han pasado 7 años y no veo libro actualizados de este lenguaje o de algun framework como Qt5 o C++17. El ingles se ha vuelto una obligacion cuando estas programando, asi que no creo que deberia limitarse a solo _libros en español_ solo libros.
Como en este link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 2):

**Titulo original:** Thinking in C++

**Autor:** [Bruce Eckel](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruce_Eckel)

[website](http://www.mindviewinc.com/Index.php)

---

Disponible de forma libre en español:

[Traducción (cuasi-terminada) del libro Thinking in C++, Volumen 1](http://arco.esi.uclm.es/~david.villa/pensar_en_C++/pensar_en_cpp-vol1.pdf)

[Traducción (INACABADA) del libro Thinking in C++, Volumen 2](http://arco.esi.uclm.es/~david.villa/pensar_en_C++/pensar_en_cpp-vol2.pdf)

---

El libro fue escrito originalmente ingles, tanto para la venta como actualmente tambien para su descarga gratuita, pues varios de los libros de este autor son creados de forma abierta y revisados por la comunidad.

El libro es del 2012, aun asi tampoco es tan antiguo, el autor comienza en el primer volumen, desde consas muy basicas pero que sirven para sentar una buena base para poder entender mejor y asimilar los conceptos que se plasman a lo largo de los dos volumenes, tocando muchos temas, necesarios para un principiante, pero no se queda ahi pues mediante se avanza en el libro, explica cosas y cosejos de como ocultar la implementacion, programacion defensiva, cuenta con algunas paginas para el uso de Make, como por ejemplo hacer una compilacion separada, hasta cuenta con un capitulo sobre c, que el autor denomina:

**Como C++ está basado en C, debería estar familiarizado con la
sintaxis de C para poder programar en C++, del mismo modo que debería
tener una fluidez razonable en álgebra para poder hacer cálculos.**

En los que se explica bastante bien las cosas, pero no solo en ese capitulo sino en el resto del libro, siendo ameno de leer, tanto si se conocen algunas cosas como si no, ademas de dentro de las explicaciones, de un tema en concreto puedes aprender cosas sobre otro tema por la forma de narrar con la que cuenta el autor para unir las cosas.

---

Puedes ver mas de sus obrar y bajarlas desde su pagina en ingles [aqui](http://www.mindviewinc.com/Books/downloads.html).

---

Pienso que de los libros para iniciarse es de lo mejorcito que he podido leer, en comparacion con otros pues es muy completo, si nunca hubiera leido un libro de c o c++, me hubiera gustado que este fuera el primero, pues bajo mi punto de vista, y teniendo en cuenta que el lenguaje de programacion c++, es muy extenso, y con muchos recovecos, este libro pienso que coge todo lo que otros libros orientados para un publico similar, y que estan de forma separada y lo pone en uno solo y muy bien explicado aun usando terminos muy correcto, lo contrario de otros que la mitad del libro es lo mismo de siempre "y mal explicado" o dejando mucho de lado y la otra mitad pasando muy de puntillas por las cosas.