# ¿Cómo se puede solicitar orientación en temas generales?

Tags: discusión, temática

Existen temas muy generales en los cuales las respuestas pueden variar, precisamente porque son temas muy generales. por ejemplo, si yo necesito orientación para **INICIAR** en lo referente a la *programación orientada a Inteligencia Artificial* debido a que NO se nada al respecto y me gustaría saber por dónde podría empezar.
Bien sea a través de un link, o un pdf, un tutorial, un video, etc..

Sería bueno poder encontrar un poco de ayuda/orientación, teniendo en cuenta que existen ya usuarios que a lo mejor dominan estos temas generales y que la "solución" en estos casos, es mas una opinión y no una respuesta técnica.

¿Se puede hacer este tipo de consultas? ¿cuál es la manera correcta de preguntar por estos temas?

Comment: la respuesta corta sería el [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=es.stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lo que le llamas "temas generales" en esta comunidad les llamamos "preguntas que se basan principalmente en opiniones". De acuerdo a [¿Qué tipo de preguntas debo evitar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) este tipo de preguntas no se permiten, sin embargo, puedes consultar a miembros de la comunidad a través de otros medios como el [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=es.stackoverflow.com) (requiere una puntuación mínima de 20).

Una forma indirecta es revisar la wiki de etiqueta de los temas que te interesan y si están incompletos, solicitar que se agregue algún tipo de información. Por ejemplo está:

- [Propuesta: Lista de libros de C++ en la etiqueta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1811/65)

También están algunas iniciativas como los webcasts y otras ideas planteadas en:

- [Objetivos del 2017 - Segunda Parte (2)](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1314/65)
- [Objetivos 2017 ¿Encuentros locales?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1371/65)